# Suggestion for learning method

Tags: interface-design, css, education, html, user-experience

Currently I am studying graphic design, in my personal time am learning Html and Css, and I want to learn UX.
What should I do? To stick with html and css and those are enough or learn a UX software?

Comment: Probably better asked at [ux.se]. Make sure to read their [on-topic page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You are studying. Are you young, or is this your second or further career? If you ask life advice questions please consider that we do not know you. If you are indeed young, then YES, study everything you can get your hands on. Your brain is unlimited at student-age; only time is your limit. If you want a deeper answer, please edit your question and give more context. And: Yeah for graphic design.

Comment: thank you for answers , am a new here my apologies if i break any rules

Comment: Do you really mean UX or do you mean UI? What is a UX software? UX is a concept, not a software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I found that it's clear that coding has very little to do with UX design.
It might be helpful to know some when interacting with product developer software engineers but otherwise you won't need it.
It's more about... well here are a couple links that may help.

https://www.mockplus.com/blog/post/does-ux-design-require-coding and 
here 
https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/ux-design/the-difference-between-ux-and-ui-design-a-laymans-guide/